# Which number belongs where?

Tags: number-property

```
List 1 | List 2 | List 3

 10        7        5
 20       11       22
 34       32       29
 72       59       33
 80       81       83
 96       99      107
130      140      150
132      190      160
```

*The numbers are picked randomly,*
*There are more possible numbers for List 2 than for List 1.*
*List 3 contains random numbers with no common properties.*

> Can you figure out the property the numbers in List 1 share?
>   Can you place the numbers from List 3 into Lists 1 & 2 according to their properties?

Comment: When you say "There are more possible numbers for List 2 than for List 1" do you mean that List 1 is *finite* and smaller than List 2, or merely that List 1 has fewer members (than List 2) that are less than any given, large number?

Comment: @msh210 Good question. The second: List 1 has fewer members (than List 2) that are less than any given, larger number.

Comment: I don't understand the question: "Can you sort the numbers of List 3 into the other two list?". What do you want us to do here?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Figure out the property of List 1&2 and put the numbers of List 3 in List 1 and List 2 according to the property.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there must be an almost-infinite number of possible solutions, so I'll post my one (*which is probably far from intended answer, but still not too far-fetched to match this exact question, I believe*).

> - List 1 contains all even numbers, which either have an even number of prime divisors, or have at least one prime divisor containing digit 3 (in decimal expansion): **10**, **20**, **34**, **72**, **80** and **96** all have 2 prime divisors each (2 and 5, 2 and 5, 2 and 17, 2 and 3, 2 and 5, 2 and 3 respectively), while **130** and **132**, despite having 3 prime divisors (2,5,13 and 2,3,11 respectively), can be divided by a prime which has a 3 in it (3 and 13, respectively).
>  - On the other hand, List 2 contains all other numbers (i.e. all odd numbers and even numbers with an odd count of prime divisors, neither of them containing a 3), e.g. **7**, **11**, **59**, **81**, **99** are all odd, while **32** ($=2^5$), **140** ($=2^2\times5\times7$) and **190** ($=2\times5\times19$) contain an odd number of prime divisors, neither of them has a 3 in its decimal expansion.

Note that

> there are more possible numbers for List 2 than for List 1 (from a set of positive integers not greater than some given number $N$, i.e. $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$), because the latter contains only part of the even numbers, while the former contains all odd and some even ones (and the count of even numbers in $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$ is never greater than the count of odd ones).

So

> **22** ($=2\times11$ - 2 prime divisors), **150** ($=2\times3\times5^2$ - 3 prime divisors but including the 3) and **160** ($=2^5\times5$ - 2 prime divisors) go into List 1, while all other numbers - **5**, **29**, **33**, **83** and **107** (being all odd) - go into List 2.